# Weird 1px lines appearing in Mosaico emails in Outlook

Tags: mosaico

I've just spent a while trying to work out what was wrong with my installation of Mosaico. I am getting random 1 pixel lines in the middle of emails and assumed I had done something wrong. I haven't as I've now found https://mosaico.io/email-client-tricks/outlook-2016-weird-1px-horizontal-lines/ and it turns out to be a bug in Outlook that Microsoft have done nothing about since 2016. Its fine with other email clients. I think I just have to live with it. It is not Mosaico specific.

Posting this hear
a) to save other people's time
b) in case anyone has come up with a workround (unlikely from other github etc posts on the subject.

Comment: You may want to put your "it turns out ..." as an Answer, so this Q gets at least one :-)

Comment: we have also heard about weird spaces between letters in a word

Answer (score 1):

As petednz suggests I am putting this as an asnwer as anythng better is unlikely...

It turns out to be a bug in Outlook that Microsoft have done nothing about since 2016. Its fine with other email clients. I think I just have to live with it. It is not Mosaico specific.